# How do I use arguments?

Tags: python, python-2.7, maya

I'm trying to select multiple curve cvs

these are my function's codes

this is `setArg` Func:

```
import maya.cmds as mc from functools import partial

def setArg(CTS, option, *args):
    option = mc.radioButtonGrp(CTS, q=True, select=True)
    if option == 1:
        cvToSel = 'first'
        print cvToSel
    elif option == 2:
        cvToSel = 'last'
        print cvToSel
    return cvToSel
```

this is `execute` Func:

```
 def execute(cvToSel, *args):
    newSel = []
    curves = mc.listRelatives (type = 'nurbsCurve', shapes = True)
    if not curves:
        print ('no curves selected')

    #mc.select(clear = True)
    #print curves
    for crv in curves:
        len = mc.getAttr(crv+'.cp', s=True, multiIndices=True)
        cvSelect = mc.intFieldGrp('numberOfCvs', q = True, value1 = True)
        numCv = len - cvSelect

        if cvToSel == 'last':
            newSel = mc.select(crv+'.cv[%d'%numCv +':%d]'%len, tgl = True)
        elif cvToSel == 'first':
            newSel = mc.select(crv+'.cv[0' + ':%d]'%cvSelect, tgl = True)

    #mc.select(newSel, replace = True)
```

this is  `ui` Func:

```
def ui():
    if mc.window('CV_Select', exists = True):
        mc.deleteUI('CV_Select')
    cvWin = mc.window('CV_Select', mxb = False)
    mc.columnLayout( adjustableColumn = True )
    mc.text( label = 'select curves' )

    mc.intFieldGrp( 'numberOfCvs', label = 'Number Of Cvs', value1 = 10 )

    ButtonOne = mc.radioButtonGrp( label='Type', labelArray2=['First CVs', 'Last CVs'], numberOfRadioButtons = 2)
    mc.button( label = 'Select CVs', command = partial(execute, ButtonOne),  align = 'center', aop = True)

    mc.showWindow('CV_Select')
     ui()
```

How do I use arguments?

Comment: Remove all the `>` characters and reformat your question to make it readable

Answer (score 0):

first dont use 'len' to store a variable. it is a python function really useful....
Here is a way to do it. You need to put your select function outside your loop
You could use -add flag but it can be really slow
Store first cvs into a variable :
(i dont have maya until Monday but I hope it will help)

```
sel_curves = mc.ls(sl=1, dag=1, type='nurbsCurve')
if sel_curves:
    to_sel = []
    cvSelect = mc.intFieldGrp('numberOfCvs', q = True, value1 = True)
    for c in sel_curves:
        cvs = mc.ls(c+'.cv[:]', fl=True)
        nb_cvs = len(cvs)
        if cvSelect > nb_cvs:
            nb_cvs = cvSelect
        if cvToSel == 'last':
            to_sel += cvs[cvSelect:]
        elif cvToSel == 'first':
            to_sel += cvs[:cvSelect]
    cmds.select(to_sel, tgl = True)
```

--- EDIT ---

Just to answer your comment question :

```
def execute(CTS,*args):
    cvToSel = setArg(CTS)
```

Comment: firstly thank you for taking the time to reply back. so where I'm stuck is trying to call the setArgs Func into the execute Func. In my setArgs Func im defining what cvToSel must be. but I don't know how to make my execute Func read it.

also earlier I tried making each radioButton a Func. In that case how would I define the def the  'cvToSel ' from multiple Func. 




firstCV(*args):
    cvToSel = 'first'
    print cvToSel
    


def lastCV(*args):
    cvToSel = 'last'
    print cvToSel

Comment: You have to think your script and forgot about your ui. There is many way to pass variables : return, dictionnary, class, partial, lambda, global, yeld. Then create the function you want to run without any ui variable. When your functions are working, you can bind your ui by passing through your variables into your function. For example here, what the difference between your setArgs and your execute ? Why setting args in another area of your ui ? Why it is not directly in your execute ?

Comment: Think that your script is something you can write as : 1) select a range of vertex, 2) randomize positions. Here you are asking, how I can select curves cvs ? We dont really understand what you are trying to do or where you are stuck. If you achieve to write what you are doing, I think it will help you a lot. Also open the links I gave you on the previous post, there is all the different way to store things within ui.....

Comment: Lastly, I have edit m answer with a simple "trying to call the setArgs Func into execute Func", and if you found an answer useful, dont forgot to mark it as resolving your question.